Question about trianguline representations
Following the notation in https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3447 a representation $V$ is split trianguline iff $D(V)$ has a basis in which the matrices of $\varphi$ and of all the elements of $\Gamma$ are upper triangular.
If $V$ is split trianguline so that $D(V)$ is etale does this imply we can find a basis of $D(V)$ such that $\text{Mat}(\varphi)$ is an upper triangular matrix in $\text{GL}_d(\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{E}^\dagger)$?
If this is not the case, is the set of representations $V$ such that one can find a basis such that $\text{Mat}(\varphi)$ is an upper triangular matrix in $\text{GL}_d(\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{E}^\dagger)$ interesting/worth studying?

You have to be very careful about what ring you're working over. There's a huge difference between $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{O_E}^{\dagger}$.

Let $H_{Q_p}$ be the absolute Galois group of $Q_p(\mu_{p^\infty})$. Representations of $H_{Q_p}$ are classified by etale $\varphi$-modules over $E^\dagger$. So the set of representations such that one can find a basis such that $Mat(\varphi)$ is an upper triangular matrix in $GL_d(O_{E^\dagger})$ is the set of representations whose restriction to $H_{Q_p}$ is upper triangular.

Correction: The above comment is a bit incorrect, here's a better answer. Let $H_{Q_p}$ be the absolute Galois group of $Q_p(\mu_{p^\infty})$. Representations of $H_{Q_p}$ are classified by etale $\varphi$-modules over $E$. So if $V$ is a representation such that one can find a basis of $D(V)$ in which $Mat(\varphi)$ is an upper triangular matrix in $GL_d(O_{E^\dagger})$, then the restriction of $V$ to $H_{Q_p}$ is upper triangular (but I'm not sure the converse holds).
